# Create a list of person

Tags: c++

I have a class Person and I need to create a list of Person. My list of person is managed by  another class, Class ListOfPerson. I create class List Of Person:

```
class ListOfPerson{
    Person list[5];
```

I want to put a person in list and i don't know how.

Comment: Please grab a C++ tutorial. Using containers is explained there.

Comment: I need to do this without STL vector...

Comment: Then use the standard library vector. Or state your requirements clearly. In the question.

Comment: You already have an array of five persons, all default-constructed. Replacing one works exactly the same as for e.g. integers - you assign a new value to it.

Comment: @Andreea If you can't use STL vector, why is your question title "Create a *vector* of person"?

Comment: Based on your updates to this question, I think you're asking how to implement a resizable container class.  Does that sound right, @Andreea?

Comment: Do you need to make a *linked list* of `Person`?

Comment: Yes. I need to create a ListOfPerson.  I have the object Person created and i want to put it in list

Comment: @Andreea if this is for a class, you may need to sit down with your teacher and discuss this.  Or do some online research.  I'm not sure that you're clear on the difference between an array, a vector, and a linked list - or which of those you're trying to create.  Good luck though!

Answer (score 2):

You want a `std::vector` of `Person`:

```
std::vector<Person> vp;
```

and add them as such:

```
Person p;
vp.push_back(p);
```

and access them:

```
vp[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a vector of `Person`s, write

```
std::vector<Person> list;
           ^^^^^^^^
     Name of type to store in vector.
```

You can then for example fill it with [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Comment: I need to do this without STL vector

Comment: @Andreea If by vector you don't mean vector, I'm afraid I do not understand the question.